# Non native 3rd-party apps not loading on Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos

Apps like DataMan, Carrot Weather or Runtastic Pro are stuck on the loading screen and eventually crash if I wait long enough.

I'm using watchOS 2.1 with 16 apps installed and have it paired to an iPhone 6 running iOS 9.2.
I've already tried unpairing the watch and then pairing it again, reinstalling the apps on both watch and iPhone as well as soft resetting both devices.

I have found these steps describing to fix the issue of not loading for native apps:

- Step 1: Perform an encrypted backup with the paired iPhone, using iTunes.
- Step 2: Erase all content and settings on your iPhone.
- Step 3: On the Apple Watch, go to the Settings app and select Erase All Contents and Settings.
- Step 4: Now restore your factory default iPhone from the iTunes backup.
- Step 5: Once the restore is complete, pair your Apple Watch with the iPhone.

But before going through the steps of completely resetting my iPhone I wanted to make sure that there's no other way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found an unusual solution to this problem:

Deleting all music from the Settings app on the iPhone and then soft resetting both devices solved the issue.